# Serial Communication Between Pycharm and Arduino

Tags: python, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Arduino cv\Outputs\Led.py", line 11, in <module>
    Arduino_Serial = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)  # Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Arduino Cv\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 33, in __init__
    super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Arduino Cv\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Arduino Cv\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)
```

I tried to create communication between pychram and arduino but my given com port cant open

Comment: Does device `COM3` exist on your system? Can you connect to it successfully using other tools (e.g., the serial monitor in the Arduino software)?

Comment: Yes Device Com3 exist on my system. Yes I successfully connect it to other tools.